# How to use component-nesting with vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm pretty new to Vue and I just can't find a good way how to use nested components alongside with vue-router.

What I have so far (some not-important code omitted):

*index.html*

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
```

*app.js*

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{ path: '/login', component: Login }]
})

const app = new Vue({
    router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

*components/Login.vue*

```
<template>
    <h1>Please log in</h1>
</template>
```

This works perfectly well - I navigate to `/login` and it shows me the message in `h1` tag. If I create more components, like `Register` or `ResetPassword` and add them to the router, it still works well. But the problem is that there is some repeating code in those components (for example, I want all the auth-related pages to have blue background) so I'd like to somehow create a "parent" component, that would define stuff that is same for all the "children" components. Something like:

```
Auth component (makes the page-background blue)
    -> Login component (shows the login form)
    -> Register component (shows the registration form)
```

I know I can do this through route's "children":

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Auth, children: [
            { path: '/login', component: Login }
            { path: '/register', component: Register }
        ]}
    ]
})
```

But with this configuration, there is the main route `path: '/'`, which is completely wrong - I don't want it here - I don't want the `Auth` component to be used "standalone" - I want it just as a "wrapper" for the nested components.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've solved this issue is to use a base path redirect.

```
{ path: '', redirect: '/to/path' },
```

in your case it would be

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Auth,
            children: [
                { path: '', redirect: '/login' },
                { path: '/login', component: Login },
                { path: '/register', component: Register }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

This ensures that

Comment: What if I want to nest another view as a child of register component? With same approach it shows white screen for me